# How to make 4 Buttons which all have the same length?

Tags: android, button

Hey I am working on a Quiz app and I am still at designing the layout. My problem right now is that whenever the text from one of my 4 buttons is different than an other buttons text, the buttons change they length and height and it just looks strange. (the textsize doesnt matter because the answers wont be more than like 20 chars)
Basically all buttons should always have the same length and height and should take 50 % of the table layout in width and height = 1/4 every button. I am sry for my bad english, I hope u kinda get the meaning :)

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Willkommen zum Quiz der Philosophen!"
        />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp">
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/antwort1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/startb_custom"
                android:shadowColor="#6AA7AB"
                android:shadowDx="5"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="A: ads"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/antwort2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/startb_custom"
                android:shadowColor="#6AA7AB"
                android:shadowDx="5"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="A: Archimedes  asdadsadasd"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/antwort3"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/startb_custom"
                android:shadowColor="#6AA7AB"
                android:shadowDx="5"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="A: Archimedes von Popelhausen"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/antwort4"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/startb_custom"
                android:shadowColor="#6AA7AB"
                android:shadowDx="5"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="A: Archimedes von asdasd "
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB8L7.jpg (this is how it looks like when the text of the buttons are different)

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` with 4 `Buttons` and `android:layout_weight = "1"`

Answer (score 0):

use **android:layout_weight="1"** in all 4 button for same size button

Answer (score 0):

try setting width and height for each rows and use `android:weightSum="2";` in each rows.

or else its better to use GridLayout as below example approach.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".GridLayoutActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Take this as a reference and use this [Link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_using_XML_Layout_Resources) to know more about GridLayouts.